# Using subdomain as primary domain

Tags: htaccess

I have a dev site at sub.example.com.

Instead of migrating the dev site to the root folder, is it possible to do something similar to [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) but using a subdomain instead of a subdirectory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is :) There are a few things you need to do, maybe I can point you in the right direction.

If you haven't already set up the virtual host on your server [here are some instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts)

If you are trying to move an existing site you will need to use a database search and replace tool to [change your Wordpress directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The site is hosted on bluehost so I am not sure if I will be able to set up a virtual host. What is that doing? I dont want to move the site. I just want the subdomain site to appear to exist on the root

Comment: There is an option to do this in the blue host control panel. Check this out: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/274